# R - Restrict function to points in a given plot "quadrant"

Tags: r, plot, cartesian-coordinates

I have a problem in which I need some function to be applied only to the points of a given cartesian plane inside a given quadrant, and plot the same quadrant. I currently am able to produce the given plot:

[image: plot]

Now, if I want the quadrant that goes from angles 50 to 130º, I can produce them with

```
abline(a=0, b=1)
abline(a=0, b=-1)
```

but that will also show the line below y = 0, which I do not want. How can I produce only the lines above y=0?

Also, how can I apply the function only to the points inside those lines/that quadrant? I have the coordinates of the points, but I do not know how to limit the function to that "range".

Please let me know if some clarification is needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those two lines (from abline) are actually at 45º and 135º,    not 50º and 130º

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the positive parts of the lines,  you can use `segments`.

```
x = rnorm(500)
y = rnorm(500)

plot(x,y)
x2 = 10*max(x) * cos(c(50/180*pi, 130/180*pi))
y2 = 10*max(x) * sin(c(50/180*pi, 130/180*pi))
segments(c(0,0), c(0,0), x2, y2)
```

[image: Sector lines]

If you want the full lines, you can use

```
plot(x,y)
abline(0, tan(50/180*pi))
abline(0, tan(130/180*pi))
```

[image: Full lines]

Comment: I want positive and negative parts as well. I guess it would be easier to "erase" half of the abline lol